# Status Bar Color - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need red status bar with white foreground for my entire app.

I'm using [flutter_statusbarcolor](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor) package for this.

I did the following so far:

1. Added the package in pubsec.yaml
2. Imported the package in my main.dart file
3. Added the following lines of codes inside the `build()` of MyApp class

```
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.red[900]);    
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
```

Result:

1. The status bar's color is red(working as it should).
2. The foreground color is white. But on restart changes to black. On hot reload, changes back to white. But on restart, it'll change back to black.

Here is my complete code:

```
import 'package:flutter_statusbarcolor/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.red[900]);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'App Title',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

I've also tried the following:

1. `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle()`
2. `appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(brightness: Brightness.light)`

Nothing's working. Can anyone please help me sustain the white foreground throughout the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this from this Doc ==> [setSystemUIOverlayStyle method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.red,
    );
    return Placeholder();  // using As your Need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*add this:*

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'
```

*use the code below after theme data*

```
 home: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
```

*Hope it work...*